# SUPEE 7405 Invalid backend model specified: catalog/category_attribute_backend_image

Tags: magento-enterprise, supee-7405

After SUPEE 7405 in Magento 1.7.0.2, getting this error in frontend.
There has been an error processing your request
Invalid backend model specified: catalog/category_attribute_backend_image

Cache management showing 500 error, order details showing paymenet method not specified.

Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting that you get this error after patching as the patch does not affect the catalog category entities.

The backend model `catalog/category_attribute_backend_image` was added to Magento a while ago (can't remember which version) and should definitely be there on a 1.7.0.2 version.

Please check that the file `app/code/code/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php` is here, you can find a mirror of it here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php

Comment: Image.php was blank, not sure why? Copy pasted the code from the git hub file and it worked :) Thanks